# No copy FIles settings in build phases XCODE

Tags: xcode

In build phrases I can't see copy files option like there is here: h

[image: copy files option]

here is how my xcode looks like:

[image: xcode]

what should I do to see Copy Files option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to the "Editor" menu and choose "Add Build Phase," which will display a sub-menu containing "Add Copy Files Build Phase". You can also type "Copy" into the help menu search box and it will list the menu items that contain the word "Copy" and point to them when you scroll over them.